# Javascript Simplification - Onclick, Onblur, Onfocus - Forms

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to simplify my javascript code below?

It works but I am quite sure that there must be a way to reduce what evidently shows my elementary javascript skills, and of course, I am trying to improve my understanding.

My HTML Code is just a simple form:

```
<div>
<form action="">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" id="un1" value="First Name"/>
       <input type="text" name="surname" id="un2" value="Surname" />
       <input type="text" name="username" id="un3" value="Email Address"/>
       <input type="button" value="Register!" />
    </form>
 </div>
```

My Javascript Code (unobtrusive):

```
window.onload = function(){
    //Field Manoeuvre1
        document.getElementById("un1").onclick = fieldClear1;
        document.getElementById("un1").onfocus = fieldClear1;
        document.getElementById("un1").onblur = fieldReplace1;

    //Field Manoeuvre2
        document.getElementById("un2").onclick = fieldClear2;
        document.getElementById("un2").onfocus = fieldClear2;
        document.getElementById("un2").onblur = fieldReplace2;

    //Field Manoeuvre3
        document.getElementById("un3").onclick = fieldClear3;
        document.getElementById("un3").onfocus = fieldClear3;
        document.getElementById("un3").onblur = fieldReplace3;
}
//Field Manoeuvre1

function fieldClear1(){
if(document.getElementById("un1").value == "First Name"){
    document.getElementById("un1").value = "";
}
}

function fieldReplace1(){
if(document.getElementById("un1").value == ""){
    document.getElementById("un1").value = "First Name";
}

} 


//Field Manoeuvre2

function fieldClear2(){
if(document.getElementById("un2").value == "Surname"){
    document.getElementById("un2").value = "";
}
}

function fieldReplace2(){
if(document.getElementById("un2").value == ""){
    document.getElementById("un2").value = "Surname";
}

}

//Field Manoeuvre3

function fieldClear3(){
if(document.getElementById("un3").value == "Email Address"){
    document.getElementById("un3").value = "";
}

function fieldReplace3(){
if(document.getElementById("un3").value == ""){
    document.getElementById("un3").value = "Email Address";
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:**

HTML:

```
<div>
<form action="">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" id="un1" class="myInput" value="First Name"/>
       <input type="text" name="surname" id="un2" class="myInput"  value="Surname" />
       <input type="text" name="username" id="un3" class="myInput"  value="Email Address"/>
       <input type="button" value="Register!" />
    </form>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
var defaultValues = {
  un1 : 'First Name',
  un2 : 'Surname',
  un3 : 'Email Address'
}



var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.myInput');
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener(['click', 'focus'], function(){
    if (this.value === defaultValues[this.id]) this.value = '';
  });

  elements[i].addEventListener('blur', function(){
    if (this.value === '') this.value = defaultValues[this.id];
  });
}
```

PS: The code is not compatible with all browsers. If you aim for browser compatibility, you should probably use a library that abstracts away the differences (ex: jQuery).

---

**SOLUTION 2:**
No change in HTML

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
        var field;

    //Field Manoeuvre1
        field = document.getElementById('un1');
        field.onclick = fieldClear.bind(field, 'First Name');
        field.onfocus = fieldClear.bind(field, 'First Name');
        field.onblur = fieldReplace.bind(field, 'First Name');

    //Field Manoeuvre2
        field = document.getElementById('un2');
        field.onclick = fieldClear.bind(field, 'Surname');
        field.onfocus = fieldClear.bind(field, 'Surname');
        field.onblur = fieldReplace.bind(field, 'Surname');

    //Field Manoeuvre3
        field = document.getElementById('un3');
        field.onclick = fieldClear.bind(field, 'Last Name');
        field.onfocus = fieldClear.bind(field, 'Last Name');
        field.onblur = fieldReplace.bind(field, 'Last Name');
}

function fieldClear(value){
    if(this.value === value) this.value = '';
}

function fieldReplace(value){
    if(this.value === '') this.value = value;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ekoJuQE/1/edit

Comment: Thanks @Tibos. Ideally I am trying to learn javascript that will be compatible over all browsers. Does Solution 2 achieve this? And does solution 1 fail to work on all browsers because it uses EventListener?

Comment: Yes and yes. IE uses attachEvent instead of addEventListener. querySelectorAll doesn't work in IE7- as well.

Comment: Unfortunately Solution 2 does not seem to be working for me. When I click on the field, the current value does not disappear, and when the field is empty and subsequently clicked off, field value becomes 'value'. :(

Comment: Fixed. I had some extra `'` that got in the way.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tibos! Solution 2 works perfectly. I will also use Solution 1 for non IE practice..though I had to separate the focus and click because for some reason I could not get it to work together! But thank you...Javascript is still a bit hocus pocus to me! haha

Comment: As i said, it's best if you abstract away the differences or use/study a library that does so. It's much cleaner to do a function that attaches the listener in different ways depending on browser than to change the way your page works.

Answer (score 0):

Use either jquery or html5

Html5 solution:

Add parameter **placeholder** to input like this

```
<input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First name" />
```

Jquery (plus attribute data-placeholder="text shown in field" on html input fields:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){

    $("#un1, #un2, #un3").on("click, focus", fieldClear(this));
    $("#un1, #un2, #un3").on("blur", fieldReplace(this));

});

function fieldClear(obj) {
    $(obj).val('');
}

function fieldReplace(obj) {
    $(obj).val($(obj).data('placeholder'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am only trying to learn javascript at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Delegated event handling can shorten things up a bit.  If you pick up jQuery, then add classes or select by element type.  Also add a data attr.

```
<input type="text" name="surname" id="un2" value="Surname" data-placeholder="Surname"/>

$('form').on('click, focus', 'input', function(e){
  $(this).val("");
});

$('form').on('blur', 'input', function(){
  $(this).val($(this).attr('data-placeholder'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am hoping to learn jquery, but for now I just want to stick with javascript.